# Pivot table with more columns

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I was trying to pivot a list of records, then i came across this :

```
 public static DataTable PivotTable<T, TColumn, TGroupRow, TRow, TData>(
        this System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T> list,
        Func<T, TColumn> column,
        Expression<Func<T, TRow>> row,
        Func<IEnumerable<T>, TData> dataSelector)
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            var rowName = ((MemberExpression)row.Body).Member.Name;
            table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(rowName));
            var columns = list.Select(column).Distinct();

            foreach (var col in columns)
                table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(col.ToString()));

            var rows = list.GroupBy(row.Compile())
                             .Select(rowGroup => new
                             {
                                 Key = rowGroup.Key,
                                 Values = columns.GroupJoin(
                                     rowGroup,
                                     c => c,
                                     r => column(r),
                                     (c, columnGroup) => dataSelector(columnGroup))
                             });

            foreach (var rowVal in rows)
            {
                var dataRow = table.NewRow();
                var items = rowVal.Values.Cast<object>().ToList();

                items.Insert(0, rowVal.Key);

                dataRow.ItemArray = items.ToArray();
                table.Rows.Add(dataRow);
            }

            return table;
        }
```

This is some solution offered from this post http://techbrij.com/pivot-c-array-datatable-convert-column-to-row-linq

my client code would be like this

```
var _dataSourceMatrix = //Some logic that get the DataTable records
var _departmentList = //Some logic that get the DataTable records

var _joinDataSourceDepartmentList = from a in _dataSourceMatrix.AsEnumerable()
                                                           join b in _departmentList.AsEnumerable()
                                                         on a.Field<int>("EntityID") equals b.Field<int>("DepartmentID")
                                                           select new { EntityName = b.Field<string>("Name"), Period = a.Field<string>("Period"), Value = a.Field<double>("Value"), EntityID = a.Field<int>("EntityID") };

_dataSourceMatrix = _joinDataSourceDepartmentList .OrderBy(x => x.Period).PivotTable(x => x.Period, x => x.EntityName, x => x.Sum(y => y.Value));
```

However, this is just the 3 columns Fields : Period, EntityName and Value could be utilize. I wish to utilize the EntityID as well. It should be one of the key to group by the record with EntityName. Is there any way to modify the PivotTable function ?

The objective to be achieve should be like this :

```
EntityName Period1, Period2, Period3, EntityID
A            Value1   Value2  Value3    1
B            Value1   Value2  Value3    2
```

Comment: What are some sample inputs and (matching) sample outputs? What do you **want** your code to do? What does it **actually** (currently) do?

Comment: See my pivot table from the other day.  I do this a lot : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45741333/how-to-convert-horizontal-data-into-vertical-from-database-to-datagridview-in-c/45741704#45741704

Comment: @jdweng thanks! your solution is makes things much more easier